# How a 3d printer moves the header vertically in a MakerBot printer

Tags: mechanism, 3d-printing

I would like to know how the header in this MakerBot printer moves in the vertical up /down direction.  Is there a detailed explanation of it including the parts involved?

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it's unclear what you're asking. If you can post some video showing the part in question in detail that would help clarify. As it stands I'm not sure what you're talking about.

Answer (score 1):

The printing head does not move in z. The table an the printed model are moving.